# kmeans algorithm display not accurate

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am trying to use the classic kmeans clustering algorithm, where the number of clusters is 2.

So, I am using a colored image and reading it in with:

```
coffeeImage = imread('coffee.png');
```

Next, I am extracting the x and y positions of the pixels with:

```
 [x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(coffeeImage, 1), 1:size(coffeeImage, 2));
```

I am combining the x and y variables into a 21,160 x 5 vector here:

```
 coffeeVector = reshape([coffeeImage(:); x(:); y(:)], [], 5);
```

Now, I want to cluster this result. I have tried the following and I am getting an Exception that states the image is too large to display. (The result is a 21,160 x 1 vector).

```
clustered = kmeans(double(coffeeImage), 2);
imshow(coffeeImage);
imshow(clustered, []);
```

I want to display the original with the new clustered variable to compare. I have reviewed the documentation on kmeans, but I am still having rendering issues. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post your actual error message and the line which causes it. What image do you expect to be displayed when inputting a 20k * 1 vector?

Comment: Well, it says it’s too large so it displays a vertical gray line. I expect to see two clusters. Aren’t you suppose to end up with a very large  x 1 vector?

Comment: a largex1 vector, displayed, is a vertical gray line

Comment: I guess I am not displaying correctly. I would like to see the two clusters displayed, if that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you use reshape with 5 columns? This completely scrambles the data. And have you even looked up what the output of `kmeans` represents?

Comment: It should get a set of points in N clusters, this case 2. Is kmeans only done with three?

Comment: So, you have an Nx5 feature vector where N represents rows*columns in the original image. You have 5 features per pixel, R,G,B,X,Y. Once clustered, you will get back an Nx1 vector of the cluster assignment, with values 1 or 2 as the first LHS argument from kmeans. If you want to view the cluster assignments as an image, you'll need to reshape the output vector into a 2-D grid that aligns with your original image: try: imshow(label2rgb(reshape(clustered,[size(coffeeImage,1),size(coffeeImage,2)])));

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I get. Just can’t seem to figure out how to properly display. I will give that a shot, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The linked example demonstrates the kmeans segmentation workflow in MATLAB, including the reshape of the resulting vector that you will need to view the result as a labeled image:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

Specifically, given the output of kmeans, which is an Nx1 vector where N = Rows*Columns in your original image, you would need to reshape the resulting labeled vector back to a 2-D grid if you want to view it as a label image. I'd also recommend using the function `labeloverlay()` to fuse the original image with the labeled image to get a visual sense of the accuracy of the segmentation:

```
clustered = kmeans(double(coffeeImage), 2);
clustered = reshape(clustered,[size(coffeeImage,1),size(coffeeImage,2)]);
figure, imshow(labeloverlay(coffeeImage,clustered));
```